# Find strings from dataframe A whose substring is present in B

Tags: r, string, substring, string-comparison

I have two dataframes A and B. 
A has full sentences and B has the recurrent phrases that I am looking for. I want to find all rows in A for which the string / part of the string is present in dataframe B.
For example,

Dataframe A has:

```
    "Sally is great"
     "John is great"
  "Sally likes peas"
 "John likes onions"
  "Jane is in Paris"
"Archie is in Paris"
```

Dataframe B has:

```
"in Paris"
"is great"
```

The output will be:

```
    "Sally is great"
     "John is great"
  "Jane is in Paris"
"Archie is in Paris"
```

since these are the rows that have a string / substring present in dataframe B.

**equivalent to WHERE x LIKE '%substring%' in SQL but for a set of substrings**

I have close to two million rows in A and ~300000 rows in B. I have considered using str_match with loop, but given the data size, it might not be a feasible solution

Comment: okay, on more search, I realized str_match_all might do the job, so testing it out. any other functions / packages I can look at?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to go through the elements of smaller set and check if it is present in the bigger set using `grep`.

```
big = c("Sally is great",
        "John is great",
        "Sally likes peas",
        "John likes onions",
        "Jane is in Paris",
        "Archie is in Paris")
small = c("in Paris",
          "is great")

big[unlist(lapply(small, function(a) grep(a, big)))]
#[1] "Jane is in Paris"   "Archie is in Paris" "Sally is great"     "John is great"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stri_detect` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
big[stri_detect(big, regex = paste(small, collapse="|"))]
#[1] "Sally is great"     "John is great"      "Jane is in Paris"  
#[4] "Archie is in Paris"
```

#### data

```
big <- c("Sally is great",
    "John is great",
    "Sally likes peas",
    "John likes onions",
    "Jane is in Paris",
    "Archie is in Paris")
small <- c("in Paris",
      "is great")
```